# Requirements.txt dependencies not being deployed with code on azure web app

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've been developing a Django site and have been testing it on a basic tier azure web app, and now its almost finished I've started a production instance, but I've had no luck deploying to it. I'm using basically the same deployment script as I was previously and the deployment logs output looks the same but when the start it fails because Django hasn't been installed, and none of the requirements have been either.

this is my deployment script

```
# Python to Linux Web App on Azure
# Build your Python project and deploy it to Azure as a Linux Web App.
# Change python version to one thats appropriate for your application.
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- Release-0.1

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureServiceConnectionId: ''

  # Web app name
  webAppName: ''

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: ''

  # Project root folder. Point to the folder containing manage.py file.
  projectRoot: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

  # Python version: 3.8
  pythonVersion: '3.8'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
      displayName: 'Use Python $(pythonVersion)'

    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip3 install setup
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(projectRoot)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload package'
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy Web App'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: $(environmentName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:

          - task: UsePythonVersion@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '$(pythonVersion)'
            displayName: 'Use Python version'

          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Deploy Azure Web App : '
            inputs:
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnectionId)
              appName: $(webAppName)
              slotName: 'staging'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
```

this is the build log

```
 ##[section]Starting: BuildJob
 ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
 Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
 Agent machine name: 'fv-az216-917'
 Current agent version: '2.182.1'
 ##[group]Operating System
 Ubuntu
 20.04.2
 LTS
 ##[endgroup]
 ##[group]Virtual Environment
 Environment: ubuntu-20.04
 Version: 20210219.1
 Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20210219.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md
 ##[endgroup]
 Current image version: '20210219.1'
 Agent running as: 'vsts'
 Prepare build directory.
 Set build variables.
 Download all required tasks.
 Downloading task: UsePythonVersion (0.181.0)
 Downloading task: CmdLine (2.182.0)
 Downloading task: ArchiveFiles (2.179.0)
 Downloading task: PublishPipelineArtifact (0.140.1)
 Checking job knob settings.
    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /opt/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
    Knob: AgentPerflog = /home/vsts/perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
 Finished checking job knob settings.
 Start tracking orphan processes.
 ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
 ##[section]Starting: Checkout DjangoPortal@Release-0.1 to s
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Get sources
 Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
 Version      : 1.0.0
 Author       : Microsoft
 Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
 ==============================================================================
 Syncing repository: DjangoPortal (Git)
 ##[command]git version
 git version 2.30.0
 ##[command]git lfs version
 git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; linux amd64; go 1.15.5)
 ##[command]git init "/home/vsts/work/1/s"
 hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
 hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
 hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
 hint: 
 hint:  git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
 hint: 
 hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
 hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
 hint: 
 hint:  git branch -m <name>
 Initialized empty Git repository in /home/vsts/work/1/s/.git/
 ##[command]git remote add origin https://2bytessoftware@dev.azure.com/2bytessoftware/BetaPortal/_git/DjangoPortal
 ##[command]git config gc.auto 0
 ##[command]git config --get-all http.https://2bytessoftware@dev.azure.com/2bytessoftware/BetaPortal/_git/DjangoPortal.extraheader
 ##[command]git config --get-all http.proxy
 ##[command]git config http.version HTTP/1.1
 ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
 remote: Azure Repos        
 remote: 
 remote: Found 1656 objects to send. (393 ms)        
 Receiving objects:   0% (1/1656)

 Receiving objects: 100% (1656/1656), 5.48 MiB | 23.08 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas:   0% (0/925)

 Resolving deltas: 100% (925/925), done.
 From https://dev.azure.com/2bytessoftware/BetaPortal/_git/DjangoPortal
  * [new branch]      Release-0.1 -> origin/Release-0.1
  * [new branch]      dev         -> origin/dev
  * [new branch]      main        -> origin/main
 ##[command]git -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: bearer ***" fetch --force --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin +163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9:refs/remotes/origin/163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9
 From https://dev.azure.com/2bytessoftware/BetaPortal/_git/DjangoPortal
  * [new ref]         163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9 -> origin/163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9
 ##[command]git checkout --progress --force 163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9
 Note: switching to '163eb3fa1f8b2c123a2d6de091d8650941e461a9'.
 
 You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
 changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
 state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
 
 If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
 do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
 
   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
 
 Or undo this operation with:
 
   git switch -
 
 Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
 
 HEAD is now at 163eb3f deploy
 ##[section]Finishing: Checkout DjangoPortal@Release-0.1 to s
 ##[section]Starting: Use Python 3.8
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Use Python version
 Description  : Use the specified version of Python from the tool cache, optionally adding it to the PATH
 Version      : 0.181.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version
 ==============================================================================
 Found tool in cache: Python 3.8.7 x64
 Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.7/x64
 Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.7/x64/bin
 ##[section]Finishing: Use Python 3.8
 ##[section]Starting: Install requirements
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Command line
 Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
 Version      : 2.182.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
 ==============================================================================
 Generating script.
 ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
 [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/3bf6fcdc-6048-4645-8fa5-2c12a1e26ff6.sh
 Collecting pip
   Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
 Installing collected packages: pip
   Attempting uninstall: pip
     Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
     Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
       Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
 Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setup
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for setup
 Collecting django-easy-pdf>=0.1.1<0.2.0
   Cloning git://github.com/geolffreym/django-easy-pdf.git to /tmp/pip-install-b8ox881f/django-easy-pdf_350c282f211f406dbd269b059bf96f23
   Running command git clone -q git://github.com/geolffreym/django-easy-pdf.git /tmp/pip-install-b8ox881f/django-easy-pdf_350c282f211f406dbd269b059bf96f23
   WARNING: Requested django-easy-pdf>=0.1.1<0.2.0 from git+git://github.com/geolffreym/django-easy-pdf.git#egg=django-easy-pdf>=0.1.1<0.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22)), but installing version 0.1.2.dev1
 Collecting asgiref
   Downloading asgiref-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
 Collecting autopep8
   Downloading autopep8-1.5.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
 Collecting Django
   Downloading Django-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.8 MB)
 Collecting pycodestyle
   Downloading pycodestyle-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
 Collecting pytz
   Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
 Collecting sqlparse
   Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
 Collecting Unipath
   Downloading Unipath-1.1.tar.gz (30 kB)
 Collecting dj-database-url
   Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
 Collecting python-decouple
   Downloading python_decouple-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
 Collecting gunicorn
   Downloading gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
 Collecting whitenoise
   Downloading whitenoise-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
 Collecting psycopg2-binary
   Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
 Collecting django-storages[azure]
   Downloading django_storages-1.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
 Collecting dj-places
   Downloading dj_places-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
 Collecting django-sendgrid-v5
   Downloading django_sendgrid_v5-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.4 kB)
 Collecting Django-Verify-Email
   Downloading Django_Verify_Email-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
 Collecting stripe
   Downloading stripe-2.56.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (204 kB)
 Collecting django-phonenumber-field[phonenumberslite]
   Downloading django_phonenumber_field-5.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
 Collecting babel
   Downloading Babel-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
 Collecting django-countries
   Downloading django_countries-7.0-py3-none-any.whl (791 kB)
 Collecting reportlab
   Downloading reportlab-3.5.59-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.6 MB)
 Collecting xhtml2pdf
   Downloading xhtml2pdf-0.2.5.tar.gz (100 kB)
 Collecting pillow>=4.0.0
   Downloading Pillow-8.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
 Collecting html5lib>=1.0
   Downloading html5lib-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
 Collecting pyPdf2
   Downloading PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz (77 kB)
 Collecting six
   Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
 Collecting python-bidi>=0.4.2
   Downloading python_bidi-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
 Collecting arabic-reshaper>=2.1.0
   Downloading arabic_reshaper-2.1.1.tar.gz (18 kB)
 Collecting future
   Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
 Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from arabic-reshaper>=2.1.0->xhtml2pdf->-r requirements.txt (line 23)) (49.2.1)
 Collecting webencodings
   Downloading webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
 Collecting toml
   Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
 Collecting phonenumberslite>=7.0.2
   Downloading phonenumberslite-8.12.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (450 kB)
 Collecting sendgrid>=5.0.0
   Downloading sendgrid-6.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (74 kB)
 Collecting python-http-client>=3.0.0
   Downloading python_http_client-3.3.2.tar.gz (7.8 kB)
 Collecting starkbank-ecdsa>=1.0.0
   Downloading starkbank-ecdsa-1.1.0.tar.gz (12 kB)
 Collecting azure-storage-blob<12.0.0,>=1.3.1
   Downloading azure_storage_blob-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
 Collecting azure-storage-common~=2.1
   Downloading azure_storage_common-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
 Collecting azure-common>=1.1.5
   Downloading azure_common-1.1.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
 Collecting requests
   Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
 Collecting python-dateutil
   Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
 Collecting cryptography
   Downloading cryptography-3.4.6-cp36-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
 Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
   Downloading certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
 Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
   Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
 Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
   Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
 Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
   Downloading urllib3-1.26.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (137 kB)
 Collecting cffi>=1.12
   Downloading cffi-1.14.5-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (411 kB)
 Collecting pycparser
   Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for django-easy-pdf, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for xhtml2pdf, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for arabic-reshaper, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for python-http-client, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for starkbank-ecdsa, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for Unipath, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for future, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyPdf2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
 Installing collected packages: pycparser, urllib3, six, idna, chardet, cffi, certifi, webencodings, sqlparse, requests, pytz, python-dateutil, pillow, future, cryptography, azure-common, asgiref, starkbank-ecdsa, reportlab, python-http-client, python-bidi, pyPdf2, html5lib, Django, azure-storage-common, arabic-reshaper, xhtml2pdf, toml, sendgrid, pycodestyle, phonenumberslite, django-storages, django-phonenumber-field, azure-storage-blob, whitenoise, Unipath, stripe, python-decouple, psycopg2-binary, gunicorn, Django-Verify-Email, django-sendgrid-v5, django-easy-pdf, django-countries, dj-places, dj-database-url, babel, autopep8
     Running setup.py install for future: started
     Running setup.py install for future: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for starkbank-ecdsa: started
     Running setup.py install for starkbank-ecdsa: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for python-http-client: started
     Running setup.py install for python-http-client: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for pyPdf2: started
     Running setup.py install for pyPdf2: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for arabic-reshaper: started
     Running setup.py install for arabic-reshaper: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for xhtml2pdf: started
     Running setup.py install for xhtml2pdf: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for Unipath: started
     Running setup.py install for Unipath: finished with status 'done'
     Running setup.py install for django-easy-pdf: started
     Running setup.py install for django-easy-pdf: finished with status 'done'
 Successfully installed Django-3.1.7 Django-Verify-Email-0.0.5 Unipath-1.1 arabic-reshaper-2.1.1 asgiref-3.3.1 autopep8-1.5.5 azure-common-1.1.26 azure-storage-blob-2.1.0 azure-storage-common-2.1.0 babel-2.9.0 certifi-2020.12.5 cffi-1.14.5 chardet-4.0.0 cryptography-3.4.6 dj-database-url-0.5.0 dj-places-4.0.0 django-countries-7.0 django-easy-pdf-0.1.2.dev1 django-phonenumber-field-5.0.0 django-sendgrid-v5-0.9.1 django-storages-1.11.1 future-0.18.2 gunicorn-20.0.4 html5lib-1.1 idna-2.10 phonenumberslite-8.12.19 pillow-8.1.1 psycopg2-binary-2.8.6 pyPdf2-1.26.0 pycodestyle-2.6.0 pycparser-2.20 python-bidi-0.4.2 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-decouple-3.4 python-http-client-3.3.2 pytz-2021.1 reportlab-3.5.59 requests-2.25.1 sendgrid-6.6.0 six-1.15.0 sqlparse-0.4.1 starkbank-ecdsa-1.1.0 stripe-2.56.0 toml-0.10.2 urllib3-1.26.3 webencodings-0.5.1 whitenoise-5.2.0 xhtml2pdf-0.2.5
 ##[section]Finishing: Install requirements
 ##[section]Starting: Archive files
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Archive files
 Description  : Compress files into .7z, .tar.gz, or .zip
 Version      : 2.179.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files
 ==============================================================================
 Found 27 files
 Archiving file: .env
 Archiving file: .git
 Archiving file: .gitignore
 Archiving file: .vscode
 Archiving file: Dockerfile
 Archiving file: LICENSE.md
 Archiving file: Procfile
 Archiving file: README.md
 Archiving file: antenv
 Archiving file: app
 ... 17 more ...
 files=.env
 files=.git
 files=.gitignore
 files=.vscode
 files=Dockerfile
 files=LICENSE.md
 files=Procfile
 files=README.md
 files=antenv
 files=app
 files=authentication
 files=azure-pipelines-1.yml
 files=azure-pipelines-old.yml
 files=azure-pipelines-release-0.1.yml
 files=core
 files=docker-compose.yml
 files=gunicorn-cfg.py
 files=manage.py
 files=modelerapp
 files=nginx
 files=package.json
 files=qaapp
 files=reports
 files=requirements.txt
 files=runtime.txt
 files=staticfiles
 files=templates
 [command]/usr/bin/zip -r /home/vsts/work/1/a/375.zip .env .git .gitignore .vscode Dockerfile LICENSE.md Procfile README.md antenv app authentication azure-pipelines-1.yml azure-pipelines-old.yml azure-pipelines-release-0.1.yml core docker-compose.yml gunicorn-cfg.py manage.py modelerapp nginx package.json qaapp reports requirements.txt runtime.txt staticfiles templates
   adding: .env (deflated 7%)
...
   adding: templates/admin/base_site.html (deflated 40%)
 ##[section]Finishing: Archive files
 ##[section]Starting: Upload package
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Publish pipeline artifact
 Description  : Publish a local directory or file as a named artifact for the current pipeline
 Version      : 0.140.1
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact
 ==============================================================================
 Uploading pipeline artifact from /home/vsts/work/1/a/375.zip for build #375
 ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session e9c26282-ca5c-469a-9647-6e557ee1bf9b
 DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session e9c26282-ca5c-469a-9647-6e557ee1bf9b
 1 files processed.
 Processed 1 files from /home/vsts/work/1/a successfully.
 Uploading 1 files from directory /home/vsts/work/1/a.
 Uploaded 0 out of 103,801,267 bytes.
 Uploading 1 files from directory /home/vsts/work/1/a.
 Uploaded 52,660,878 out of 103,801,267 bytes.
 Uploaded 82,356,390 out of 103,801,447 bytes
 Content upload is done!
 
 Content upload statistics:
 Total Content: 207.4 MB
 Physical Content Uploaded: 78.0 MB
 Logical Content Uploaded: 82.4 MB
 Compression Saved: 4.3 MB
 Deduplication Saved: 125.1 MB
 Number of Chunks Uploaded: 1,047
 Total Number of Chunks: 5,036
 
 Associated artifact 126 with build 375
 ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session e9c26282-ca5c-469a-9647-6e557ee1bf9b
 Uploading pipeline artifact finished.
 ##[section]Finishing: Upload package
 ##[section]Starting: Checkout DjangoPortal@Release-0.1 to s
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Get sources
 Description  : Get sources from a repository. Supports Git, TfsVC, and SVN repositories.
 Version      : 1.0.0
 Author       : Microsoft
 Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=798199)
 ==============================================================================
 Cleaning any cached credential from repository: DjangoPortal (Git)
 ##[section]Finishing: Checkout DjangoPortal@Release-0.1 to s
 ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
 Cleaning up task key
 Start cleaning up orphan processes.
 ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
 ##[section]Finishing: BuildJob
```

And this is the deployment log

```
 ##[section]Starting: DeploymentJob
 ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
 Agent name: 'Hosted Agent'
 Agent machine name: 'fv-az192-236'
 Current agent version: '2.182.1'
 ##[group]Operating System
 Ubuntu
 20.04.2
 LTS
 ##[endgroup]
 ##[group]Virtual Environment
 Environment: ubuntu-20.04
 Version: 20210219.1
 Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20210219.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-README.md
 ##[endgroup]
 Current image version: '20210219.1'
 Agent running as: 'vsts'
 Prepare build directory.
 Set build variables.
 Download all required tasks.
 Downloading task: DownloadPipelineArtifact (1.2.5)
 Downloading task: UsePythonVersion (0.181.0)
 Downloading task: AzureWebApp (1.182.0)
 Checking job knob settings.
    Knob: AgentToolsDirectory = /opt/hostedtoolcache Source: ${AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY} 
    Knob: AgentPerflog = /home/vsts/perflog Source: ${VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG} 
 Finished checking job knob settings.
 Start tracking orphan processes.
 ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
 ##[section]Starting: Download Artifact
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Download pipeline artifact
 Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
 Version      : 1.2.5
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
 ==============================================================================
 Download from the specified build: #375
 Download artifact to: /home/vsts/work/1/
 ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 13ea3dca-de9a-4a81-b2b7-013f9bc2809a
 Downloading 1 pipeline artifacts...
 DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 13ea3dca-de9a-4a81-b2b7-013f9bc2809a
 Start downloading artifact - drop
 Minimatch patterns: [**]
 Filtered 1 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.
 Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 103.8 MB (0%).
 Downloaded 103.8 MB out of 103.8 MB (100%).
 
 Download statistics:
 Total Content: 103.8 MB
 Physical Content Downloaded: 99.5 MB
 Compression Saved: 4.3 MB
 Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
 Chunks Downloaded: 1,337
 Nodes Downloaded: 4
 
 Download completed.
 ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 13ea3dca-de9a-4a81-b2b7-013f9bc2809a
 Downloading artifact finished.
 ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifact
 ##[section]Starting: Use Python version
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Use Python version
 Description  : Use the specified version of Python from the tool cache, optionally adding it to the PATH
 Version      : 0.181.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/use-python-version
 ==============================================================================
 Found tool in cache: Python 3.8.7 x64
 Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.7/x64
 Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.7/x64/bin
 ##[section]Finishing: Use Python version
 ##[section]Starting: Deploy Azure Web App : staging
 ==============================================================================
 Task         : Azure Web App
 Description  : Deploy an Azure Web App for Linux or Windows
 Version      : 1.182.0
 Author       : Microsoft Corporation
 Help         : https://aka.ms/azurewebapptroubleshooting
 ==============================================================================
 Got service connection details for Azure App Service:''
 Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
 Deploy logs can be viewed at https://-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/37a1ee6e-7258-4e82-b769-2ab660a88de9/log
 Successfully deployed web package to App Service.
 Successfully updated deployment History at https://-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/3751614723426245
 App Service Application URL: http://-staging.azurewebsites.net
 ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure Web App : staging
 ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
 Cleaning up task key
 Start cleaning up orphan processes.
 ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
 ##[section]Finishing: DeploymentJob
```

then when the app runs this is what happens

```
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "/home/site/wwwroot/core/wsgi.py", line 9, in <module>
     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
 [2021-03-02 04:42:36 +0000] [38] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 38)
 [2021-03-02 04:42:36 +0000] [36] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
 [2021-03-02 04:42:36 +0000] [36] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I went into the SCM bash console and checked `(antenv) root@39e2ab319aff:/home/site/wwwroot# ls ./antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages` and all the files were there,
but doing pip freeze showed that none of the depenences were installed, and when I try python manage.py whatever it also doesnt have the dependances installed

I'm at a loss as to what it could be, im sure it is probably something simple that I'm missing, ive compared the logs to the logs from the test instance that is working, and the logs are basically identical

Comment: Did you check the project structure in kudu site? `https://{yourappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/wwwroot/` Check if the `manage.py` and `requirements.txt` exist or not.

Comment: @DorisLv yeah, they are there, everything in my source control is there

Comment: Does my answer help? Would you mind accept it as the answer for others to refer?

Answer (score 0):

I test this workflow with a simple Django app without any problem.

The two things different with yours is:

1. **I use the version `python 3.7` but you use `python 3.8`**
2. **I use `pip` command but you use `pip3`:**

   ```
    - script: |
        python -m venv antenv
        source antenv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install setup
        pip install -r requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(projectRoot)
      displayName: "Install requirements"
   ```

As we can see from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-build-automation), it also use pip rather than pip3.

If it not help, just like my comment, maybe your important file is not exists in the root path, check if this workflow works for you:

```
# Python Django
# Test a Django project on multiple versions of Python.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.5
    architecture: 'x64'

- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Export project path'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'inline'
    script: |
      """Search all subdirectories for `manage.py`."""
      from glob import iglob
      from os import path
      # Python >= 3.5
      manage_py = next(iglob(path.join('**', 'manage.py'), recursive=True), None)
      if not manage_py:
          raise SystemExit('Could not find a Django project')
      project_location = path.dirname(path.abspath(manage_py))
      print('Found Django project in', project_location)
      print('##vso[task.setvariable variable=projectRoot]{}'.format(project_location))
- script: |
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel django
    pip install -r requirements.txt
    pip install unittest-xml-reporting
  displayName: 'Install prerequisites'

- script: |
    pushd '$(projectRoot)'
    python manage.py test --testrunner xmlrunner.extra.djangotestrunner.XMLTestRunner --no-input
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  displayName: 'Run tests'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: "**/TEST-*.xml"
    testRunTitle: 'Python $(PYTHON_VERSION)'
```